# Change Style Sheet with php variable that connecting to mysql

Tags: php, html, css

Well I want stylesheet URLs to be stored in the database, and change the stylesheets href by variables in html tags.

But nothing happen when i using this code:

```
 global $theme_addresss;
    global $showdetail_dbtadbirusers;
    require 'displaycustomersdb.php'; /*this file store usercode in variable via session*/
    $sql_changetheme = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT profile_theme FROM tusers WHERE usercodecode='{$usercodecode}'");
    $sql_result_changetheme = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_changetheme);
   $theme_addresss = $sql_result_changetheme['profile_theme'];

<link rel="stylesheet" href='<?php  echo $theme_addresss; ?>'>
```

Comment: Are you trying to include single css file or multiple?

Comment: Can you inspect the result and see what it is?

Comment: Yes i have 3 css file that their addressees store in users table, then i want css file address store in variable and i put that variable into HTML tag. if i can fix this problem then i'll use swich case.

Comment: @YaakovAinspan When i echo variable it's working and show data. but it's not working when i put variable into the html tag.

Comment: You have an extra $ sign in `global $$theme_addresss`.

Comment: @Peter Thank You, I see it and fixed it but noting happen and still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out what is the problem, the code is fine. i just put `<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php  echo $theme_addresss; ?>">` into the other page of my website and **it worked!**

Answer (score 0):

Can you try change single quote to double quote around href and see if it works?

`<link rel="stylesheet" href=“<?php  echo $theme_addresss; ?>”>`

Comment: not working, it's only working when i insert css address into variable. 
like: echo $theme_addresss="css/style.css";